# CVXOPT Module Python - DLL load failed: The specified module cannot be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, cvxopt

I'm unable to run this code. When I run this it gives me an error which, from what I understand it means that it is unable to import cvxopt.base module. 
If there is anyone who has encountered this error or knows the solution to this problem, please reach out.

I'm sharing the code & trace of Python interface below:

The Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np

from numpy import linalg
from cvxopt import solvers

def Twin_plane_1(R,S,C1,Epsi1,regulz1):
    StS = np.dot(S.T,S)
    # for regularization we add identity matrix with wt. before inversion
    StS = StS + regulz1*(np.identity(StS.shape[0]))
    StSRt = linalg.solve(StS,R.T)
    RtStSRt = np.dot(R,StSRt)
    RtStSRt = (RtStSRt+(RtStSRt.T))/2
    m2 = R.shape[0]
    e2 = -np.ones((m2,1))
    solvers.options['show_progress'] = False
    vlb = np.zeros((m2,1))
    vub = C1*(np.ones((m2,1)))
    # x<=vub
    # x>=vlb -> -x<=-vlb
    # cdx<=vcd
    cd = np.vstack((np.identity(m2),-np.identity(m2)))
    vcd = np.vstack((vub,-vlb))
    alpha = solvers.qp(matrix(RtStSRt,tc='d'),matrix(e2,tc='d'),matrix(cd,tc='d'),matrix(vcd,tc='d'))#,matrix(0.0,(1,m1)),matrix(0.0))#,None,matrix(x0))
    alphasol = np.array(alpha['x'])
    z = -np.dot(StSRt,alphasol)
    w1 = z[:len(z)-1]
    b1 = z[len(z)-1]
    return [w1,b1]
```

The Trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\sau\Downloads\Twin-SVM-master\Twin-SVM-master\TwinPlane1.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from cvxopt import solvers   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\cvxopt__init__.py", line 50, in
>   
>       import cvxopt.base ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: What is your question? Please add more details to your question. You can see the [help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is largely meaningless. There's no question, no code and no context. The only clue is the rather obvious "module cannot be found" sentence. Presumably the module isn't where your code thinks it should be. I don't know python (this just came up in a review queue) but I guess you have to put the module file(s) in a specific location for the application to use them. Check whether you've done that in the environment in question.

Comment: @ADyson I have added the code dude.

Comment: ok and what about your missing module? Have you checked for its existence on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue...try this:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += r';C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\Library\\mingw- 
w64\\bin'
```

Comment: Please explain more and show where the problem was and why this method will work